# List of available filters

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, swift, ios-frameworks

I'm looking for the list of filters provided by Apple to apply on Images.

Summery : I want to create an application which will allow user to edit photos. I'm looking into Core Image Programming Guide, but not able to get full list of filters already available. Right now referring [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIWhitePointAdjust)

Also I need to build this application with new language swift. And it would be my first swift app.So can we use this framework with Swift?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are on correct page, everything listed on the page you can use as a filter, click on each options to get more details.

Comment: Thank you iphoneic for quick response. So can I say, filters mentioned in that link are the default filters provided by Apple?

Comment: Yes they are default filters provided by Apple for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a website called [CIFilter.io](https://cifilter.io) which lists all the Core Image filters and their parameters (to learn more about how it works you can read [this blog post](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/cifilterio)). The documentation archive link you mentioned lists most of them, but as far as I know, CIFilter.io is the most up to date reference for documentation.

CIFilter is usable in Swift. I'd recommend reading [this other blog post](https://noahgilmore.com/blog/cifilter-colorwheel/) which provides example code for generating a color wheel using CIHueSaturationValueGradient for an example.